# Return first match of Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to perform a regex match on a string in Ruby and have it short-circuit on the first match.

The string I'm processing is long and from what it looks like the standard way (`match` method) would process the whole thing, collect each match, and return a MatchData object containing all matches.

```
match = string.match(/regex/)[0].to_s
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You could try [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) (as in `variableName[/regular expression/]`).

This is an example output from IRB:

```
names = "erik kalle johan anders erik kalle johan anders"
# => "erik kalle johan anders erik kalle johan anders"
names[/kalle/]
# => "kalle"
```

Comment: Is this not doing a match and returning the first result behind the scenes ?

Comment: After some benchmarking with various length strings and looking at the C source, it turns out Regex.match does short-circuit and only finds the first match.

Comment: Neat, didn't know about this shortcut.

Comment: Is there some documentation on this shortcut?  I searched high and low for what I thought was a relatively simple task and only solved my issue after finding this. Thanks!

Comment: This work well but if you have no matches, it returns nil instead of an empty string.

Comment: @dmourati You can find this feature documented in [String#\[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). Thanks for asking about the doc, because in reading it I found the `capture` argument – which lets you return a capture instead of the full match.

Answer (score 89):

You can use `[]`: (which is like `match`)

```
"foo+account2@gmail.com"[/\+([^@]+)/, 1] # matches capture group 1, i.e. what is inside ()
# => "account2"
"foo+account2@gmail.com"[/\+([^@]+)/]    # matches capture group 0, i.e. the whole match
# => "+account2"
```

Answer (score 26):

If only an existence of a match is important, you can go with

```
/regexp/ =~ "string"
```

Either way, `match` should only return the first hit, while `scan` searches throughout entire string. Therefore if

```
matchData = "string string".match(/string/)
matchData[0]    # => "string"
matchData[1]    # => nil - it's the first capture group not a second match
```

Comment: If you are fine with using the perlish `$1`, etc then `=~` can return the match quite okay.

Answer (score 13):

I am not yet sure whether this feature is awesome or just totally crazy, but your regex can define local variables.

```
/\$(?<dollars>\d+)\.(?<cents>\d+)/ =~ "$3.67" #=> 0
dollars #=> "3"
```

(Taken from http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html).

Comment: Awesome feature! Just what I needed

Comment: Caveat: it only works when `regex =~ string` not when `string =~ regex`

Answer (score 2):

A Regular Expression (regex) is nothing but a finite state machine (FSM).

An FSM attempts to answer the question "Is this state possible or not?"

It keeps attempting to make a pattern match until a match is found (success), or until all paths are explored and no match was found (failure).

On success, the question "Is this state possible or not?" has been answered with a "yes". Hence no further matching is necessary and the regex returns.

See [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions_and_Finite_State_Machines) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/525043/1243123) for more on this.

Further: [here is an interesting example](http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/) to demonstrate how regex works. Here, a regex is used to detect if a give number is prime. This example is in perl, but it can as well be written in ruby.