# Short example of regular expression converted to a state machine?

Tags: regex, state-machine, fsm

In the Stack Overflow podcast #36 (https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/podcast-36/), this opinion was expressed:
Once you understand how easy it is to set up a state machine, you’ll never try to use a regular expression inappropriately ever again.

I've done a bunch of searching.  I've found some academic papers and other complicated examples, but I'd like to find a simple example that would help me understand this process.  I use a lot of regular expressions, and I'd like to make sure I never use one "inappropriately" ever again.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a finite state machine? Joel's point is that implementing an FSM can be simpler and easier to understand/maintain than a very complex regular expression. This is true sometimes. Also, you could gain both readability and performance. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure, although you'll need more complicated examples to truly understand how REs work. Consider the following RE:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

which is a typical identifier (must start with alpha and can have any number of alphanumeric and undescore characters following, including none). The following pseudo-code shows how this can be done with a finite state machine:

```
state = FIRSTCHAR
for char in all_chars_in(string):
    if state == FIRSTCHAR:
            if char is not in the set "A-Z" or "a-z":
                error "Invalid first character"
            state = SUBSEQUENTCHARS
            next char
    if state == SUBSEQUENTCHARS:
            if char is not in the set "A-Z" or "a-z" or "0-9" or "_":
                error "Invalid subsequent character"
            state = SUBSEQUENTCHARS
            next char
```

Now, as I said, this is a very simple example. It doesn't show how to do greedy/nongreedy matches, backtracking, matching within a line (instead of the whole line) and other more esoteric features of state machines that are easily handled by the RE syntax.

That's why REs are so powerful. The actual finite state machine code required to do what a one-liner RE can do is usually very long and complex.

The best thing you could do is grab a copy of some lex/yacc (or equivalent) code for a specific simple language and see the code it generates. It's not pretty (it doesn't have to be since it's not supposed to be read by humans, they're supposed to be looking at the lex/yacc code) but it may give you a better idea as to how they work.

Answer (score 30):

A rather convenient way to help look at this to use python's little-known re.DEBUG flag on any pattern:

```
>>> re.compile(r'<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>', re.DEBUG)
literal 60
subpattern 1
  in
    range (65, 90)
  max_repeat 0 65535
    in
      range (65, 90)
      range (48, 57)
at at_boundary
max_repeat 0 65535
  not_literal 62
literal 62
subpattern 2
  min_repeat 0 65535
    any None
literal 60
literal 47
groupref 1
literal 62
```

The numbers after 'literal' and 'range' refer to the integer values of the ascii characters they're supposed to match.

Comment: +1, was waiting for this little gem to surface. Does anyone know where its output is documented? I've never found anything..

Answer (score 21):

Make your own on the fly!

http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/???

[image: A finite state machine]

This is a really nicely put together tool which visualises regular expressions as FSMs. It doesn't have support for some of the syntax you'll find in real-world regular expression engines, but certainly enough to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: That site's not that useful - put in [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,4} and see what claptrap is comes out with :-)

Comment: Pax, ouch :/ too bad, such a nice site but can't compile that simple regex

Comment: Yep, can't handle repeat qualifiers unfortunately... But you *can* have semantically equivalent claptrap with [A-Za-z]\w{0,4}! He probably left them out for simplicity's sake. Plus repeat qualifiers can really blow out your FSM - the UI would quickly become useless.

Comment: "This particular implementation doesn't know about anchors, assertions, non-greedy and bounded qualifiers, collation elements, or backreferences." - that's quite a laundry list of no-can-do's.

Comment: Admittedly, the first RE I gave it used a repeat qualifier, but I think non-greedy and repeat qualifiers are the only things in the TODO list I use day to day, if at all! It's still a useful tool for learning how REs map to FSMs, as the OP requested.

Comment: Unfortunately, the tool appears to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

Is the question "How do I choose the states and the transition conditions?", or "How do I implement my abstract state machine in Foo?"

### How do I choose the states and the transition conditions?

I usually use FSMs for fairly simple problems and choose them intuitively. In [my answer to another question about regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328387/regex-to-replace-all-n-in-a-string-but-no-those-inside-code-code-tag/328403#328403), I just looked at the parsing problem as one of being either **`Inside`** or **`outside`** a tag pair, and wrote out the transitions from there (with a beginning and ending state to keep the implementation clean).

### How do I implement my abstract state machine in Foo?

If your implementation language supports a structure like `c`'s `switch` statement, then you switch on the current state and process the input to see which action and/or transition too perform next.

Without `switch`-like structures, or if they are deficient in some way, you `if` style branching. *Ugh.*

Written all in one place in `c` the example I linked would look something like this:

```
token_t token;
state_t state=BEGIN_STATE;
do {
   switch ( state.getValue() ) {
   case BEGIN_STATE;
      state=OUT_STATE;
      break;
   case OUT_STATE:
      switch ( token.getValue() ) {
         case CODE_TOKEN:
            state = IN_STATE;
            output(token.string());
            break;
         case NEWLINE_TOKEN;
            output("<break>");
            output(token.string());
            break;
         ...
      }
      break;
   ...
   }
} while (state != END_STATE);
```

which is pretty messy, so I usually rip the `state` cases out to separate functions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone has better examples, but you could [check this post by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/14/named-formats-redux.aspx), which has an example of a regular expression and a state machine doing the same thing (there's a previous post with a few more regex examples in there as well I think..)

Check the "HenriFormatter" on that page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what academic papers you've already read but it really isn't that difficult to understand how to implement a finite state machine. There are some interesting mathematics but to idea is actually very trivial to understand. The easiest way to understand an FSM is through input and output (actually, this comprises most of the formal definition, that I won't describe here). A "state" is essentially just describing a set of input and outputs that have occurred and can occur from a certain point.

Finite state machines are easiest to understand via diagrams. For example:

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/7571/mathfinitestatemachinedco3.gif](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/7571/mathfinitestatemachinedco3.gif)

All this is saying is that if you begin in some state q0 (the one with the Start symbol next to it) you can go to other states. Each state is a circle. Each arrow represents an input or output (depending on how you look at it). Another way to think of an finite state machine is in terms of "valid" or "acceptable" input. There are certain output strings that are NOT possible certain finite state machines; this would allow you to "match" expressions.

Now suppose you start at q0. Now, if you input a 0 you will go to state q1. However, if you input a 1 you will go to state q2. You can see this by the symbols above the input/output arrows.

Let's say you start at q0 and get this input

0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1

This means you have gone through states (no input for q0, you just start there):

q0 -> q1 -> q0 -> q1 -> q0 -> q2 -> q3 -> q3

Trace the picture with your finger if it doesn't make sense. Notice that q3 goes back to itself for both inputs 0 and 1.

Another way to say all this is "If you are in state q0 and you see a 0 go to q1 but if you see a 1 go to q2." If you make these conditions for each state you are nearly done defining your state machine. All you have to do is have a state variable and then a way to pump input in and that is basically what is there.

Ok, so why is this important regarding Joel's statement? Well, building the "ONE TRUE REGULAR EXPRESSION TO RULE THEM ALL" can be very difficult and also difficult to maintain modify or even for others to come back and understand. Also, in some cases it is more efficient.

Of course, state machines have many other uses. Hope this helps in some small way. Note, I didn't bother going into the theory but there are some interesting proofs regarding FSMs.

Comment: Looks like the image link is broken. All I see is a purple box with "gallery.hd.org" in it.

Comment: @joel.neely, hm I don't know the image works for me. SO needs to do image hosting. @Pax, not sure what you mean. :)

Comment: It's a quote from the Sneakers movie.

Comment: The image link is broken again. Please upload to Imgur.