# How to tokenize the regexp pattern ITSELF?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, tokenize

Lots of questions on how to tokenize some string using regexp.

I'm looking however, to tokenize the regexp pattern itself, I'm sure there are some posts on the subject but I cannot find them.

Examples:

```
^\w$                    -> ['^', '\w', '&']
[3-7]*                  -> ['[3-7]*']
\w+\s\w+                -> ['\w+', '\s', '\w+']
(xyz)*\s[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]? -> ['(xyz)*','\s','[a-zA-Z]+','[0-9]?']
```

I'm assuming this work is done in python under the hood when some `regexp` function is called.

Comment: You can think of regular expressions as shorthand for finite state machines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525004/short-example-of-regular-expression-converted-to-a-state-machine

Comment: One of the problems is constructions such as `[-z]` vs. `[a-z]` – meta codes change their meaning, depending on their position. A few other ones: `[*]*` and `[[]`. I think strict left-to-right parsing is the only way to do so.

Comment: BTW Python uses [boost](http://www.boost.org/) under the hood.

Comment: From the question linked by @AndreiSavin, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/525068/2877364).  Also, [the parser](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/src/regparse.c) from [oniguruma](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma) ... but that's not exactly implemented in python :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One place to start: the [PyPy project](http://pypy.org/) has an implementation of Python in (mostly) Python.  The [re.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/cc6165679b16c61a7f21a4678fe915fe428b95b0/lib-python/2.7/re.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) in the source distribution calls [sre-compile.c:_compile()](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/cc6165679b16c61a7f21a4678fe915fe428b95b0/lib-python/2.7/sre_compile.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#sre_compile.py-64) to do the work.  You might be able to hack that to provide the output form you want.

**Edit** Also, the Javascript [XRegExp library](http://xregexp.com/) parses regexes in an extended syntax and renders them to standard syntax.  The [parser routine](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/src/xregexp.js#L557) may help you.