# Regex to match value only once in text value

Tags: ruby, regex

I am dealing with a dirty data source that has some key value pairs I have to extract. for example:

> First Name = John   Last Name = Smith   Home Phone = 555-333-2345   Work Phone =  Email = john.doe@email.com  Zip From = 11772 Zip To = 11782  First Name = John   First Name = John

To extract the First Name, I am using this regular expression:

```
/First Name = ([a-zA-Z]*)/
```

How do I prevent multiple matches in the case where the First Name is duplicated as shown above?

Here is a [version of this on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/YjAJjkKUmE).

Comment: is "First Name" always at the beginning of the line? If so you can use this (^First Name = [a-zA-Z]*)

Comment: Try the answer found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519572/return-first-match-of-ruby-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match) will only get the first match (you would use [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) to get all):

```
str.match(/First Name = ([a-zA-Z]*)/).captures.first
#=> "John"
```

(given your string is in `str`)

Answer (score 0):

[] will also give you the first match:

```
str[/First Name = ([a-zA-Z]*)/, 1]
```

The 1 means the first capture group

Answer (score 0):

/^First Name = ([a-zA-Z]*)/

this will work too. just add ^ to indicate start of line