# Regex match everything up to first period

Tags: ruby, regex

Trying to get a lazy regex match of everything up until the first period of a sentence.

e.g. Just want to get "jack and jill." from this sentence:
"jack and jill. went up the hill. to fetch a pail."

`/.+\./` matches the whole sentence ([example](http://rubular.com/r/HuVqEBOm1M))
`/(.+?\.)/` matches each instance ([example](http://rubular.com/r/yPGjgGgaK3))

Is there a way to just match the first instance?

Comment: For that demo site use caret `^(.+?\.)`

Comment: Use the `match` method with the second pattern.

Comment: Like what @revo has answered, it could also do without the parentheses [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tzaQhs/1/), unless you somehow want the match to be in a capture group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return first match of Ruby regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519572/return-first-match-of-ruby-regex)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
/^([^.]+)/
```

Let's break it down,

- `^` is the newline anchor
- `[^.]` this matches any character that's not a period
- `\+` to take until a period

And the expression is encapsulated with () to capture it.

Comment: *"^ is the beginning of string anchor"*: No it's wrong, in Ruby `^` matches the start of a line (not of the string). The anchor for the start of the string is `\A`

Comment: Note that when `.` appears within square brackets, it does not need to be escaped. `[\.]` is the same as `[.]`. (And the negating carat doesn't change this.)

Comment: You're correct, I never have a reason to use \A so the concept blends together for me. Updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the first occurrence, do not choose the `scan` method that returns all results in the string. You can use the match method that returns a MatchData instance, but you can also simply write:

```
> "jack and jill. went up the hill. to fetch a pail."[/.+?\./]
 => "jack and jill."
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use a regex, but there are other options.

```
str = "jack and jill. went up the hill. supposedly to fetch a pail of water."
str[0..i] if i = str.index('.')
  #=> "jack and jill."

str = "three blind mice"
str[0..i] if i = str.index('.')
  #=> nil
```